# How to get data from previous dataframe row based on conditions?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following current dataframe and desired dataframe shown below. I have tried a few method but was unable to get my desired output.

```
data = [['Period', 'Company/Title', 'Personnel No.', 'Start Date', 'End Date'],
   ['01/01/1980 - 31/12/1982', 'AAA', '0', '01/01/1980', '31/12/1982'],
   ['01/01/1980', 'Typist', '0', '01/01/1980', ''],
   ['01/07/1990 - 31/05/1994', 'BBB', '0', '01/07/1990', '31/05/1994'],
   ['01/07/1990', 'Clerk 1', '0', '01/07/1990', ''],
   ['01/01/1994', 'Clerk 2', '0', '01/01/1994', ''],
   ['01/12/1993 - 05/06/1994', 'ZZZ', '1', '01/12/1993', '05/06/1994'],
   ['01/12/1993', 'ZZZ', '1', '01/12/1993', '']]

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = [data[0]])
data_df
```

[image]

```
desire_output = [['Period', 'Company/Title', 'Personnel No.', 'Start Date', 'End Date'],
       ['01/01/1980 - 31/12/1982', 'AAA', '0', '01/01/1980', '31/12/1982'],
       ['01/01/1980', 'AAA - Typist', '0', '01/01/1980', '31/12/1982'],
       ['01/07/1990 - 31/05/1994', 'BBB', '0', '01/07/1990', '31/05/1994'],
       ['01/07/1990', 'BBB - Clerk 1', '0', '01/07/1990', '31/12/1993'],
       ['01/01/1994', 'BBB - Clerk 2', '0', '01/01/1994', '31/05/1994'],
       ['01/12/1993 - 05/06/1994', 'ZZZ', '1', '01/12/1993', '05/06/1994'],
       ['01/12/1993', 'ZZZ - Executive', '1', '01/12/1993', '05/06/1994']]
desire_output_df = pd.DataFrame(desire_output[1:], columns = [desire_output[0]])
desire_output_df
```

[image]

- Can imagine the data is from linkedin in where the first row contains the total period a person is with a organisation. Next 2 rows should the breakdown of each row within the same organisation.
- Row with title will get company name from row with period that contains dash "-"
- For personnel no. with multiple role within the same company, the end date would be the previous row date - day.

I did a indx, row in data that check if "-" in row['Period'] and get the company name and manage to store the company name with the role (e.g. "AAA- Typist" but unable to solve the rest. Appreciate any advice on how can i do this.

Thank you!

Comment: The end date requirement is hard to understand. Why the row 3 has 31/12/1993 and row 4 has  31/05/1994?

Comment: @J.Choi Row 2 show the period the person was with the company BBB, from 01/07/1990 - 31/05/1994.

Row 3 & 4 only have the start date for the position which is 01/07/1990 and 01/01/1994 respectively.

I need to input the end date where row 3 end date is row 4 start date minus 1. Was thinking how can i do a loop to get the value? or any other way i could do this? thanks!

Comment: I did not understand how row 3 end date is `31/12/1993`?

Comment: Can you be more clear regarding how `Personnel No.` and `End Date` column is calculated?

Comment: @PrakashDahal row 3 end date is calculated based on row 4 start date minus 1 day.

Personnel No. is not calculated, it is a unique identifier for each personnel. e.g row 1, there is only 1 row so the end date will follow row 0 end date. For row 3 & 4 where company have more than 1 date,  row 4 will follow row 2 end date and row 3 will be row 4 start date minus one day. Hope this clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to migrate your data into a proper database.

Anyway, here is a working code. The key idea for end date process is using `shift` instead of loop. Typo-like values in the original question are changed.

The code is quite ugly and there may be better method to solve your question.

###### 1. Load data

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

data = [['Period', 'Company/Title', 'Personal No.', 'Start Date', 'End Date'],
   ['01/01/1980 - 31/12/1982', 'AAA', '0', '01/01/1980', '31/12/1982'],
   ['01/01/1980', 'Typist', '0', '01/01/1980', ''],
   ['01/07/1990 - 31/05/1994', 'BBB', '0', '01/07/1990', '31/05/1994'],
   ['01/07/1990', 'Clerk 1', '0', '01/07/1990', ''],
   ['01/01/1994', 'Clerk 2', '0', '01/01/1994', ''],
   ['01/12/1993 - 05/06/1994', 'ZZZ', '1', '01/12/1993', '05/06/1994'],
   ['01/12/1993', 'Executive', '1', '01/12/1993', '']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = [data[0]])
```

Result

```
                    Period Company/Title Personal No.  Start Date    End Date
0  01/01/1980 - 31/12/1982           AAA            0  01/01/1980  31/12/1982
1               01/01/1980        Typist            0  01/01/1980            
2  01/07/1990 - 31/05/1994           BBB            0  01/07/1990  31/05/1994
3               01/07/1990       Clerk 1            0  01/07/1990            
4               01/01/1994       Clerk 2            0  01/01/1994            
5  01/12/1993 - 05/06/1994           ZZZ            1  01/12/1993  05/06/1994
6               01/12/1993     Executive            1  01/12/1993
```

###### 2. Process for Company/Title

```
df['Company'] = df['Company/Title'].loc[df.apply(lambda row: '-' in row['Period'], axis=1)]
df['Company'] = df['Company'].fillna(method='ffill')

df['Title'] = df['Company/Title'].loc[df.apply(lambda row: '-' not in row['Period'], axis=1)]

df['Company/Title'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Company'] if pd.isna(row['Title']) else row['Company'] + ' - ' + row['Title'], axis=1)
```

Result

```
                    Period    Company/Title Personal No.  Start Date  \
0  01/01/1980 - 31/12/1982              AAA            0  01/01/1980   
1               01/01/1980     AAA - Typist            0  01/01/1980   
2  01/07/1990 - 31/05/1994              BBB            0  01/07/1990   
3               01/07/1990    BBB - Clerk 1            0  01/07/1990   
4               01/01/1994    BBB - Clerk 2            0  01/01/1994   
5  01/12/1993 - 05/06/1994              ZZZ            1  01/12/1993   
6               01/12/1993  ZZZ - Executive            1  01/12/1993   

     End Date Company      Title  
0  31/12/1982     AAA        NaN  
1                 AAA     Typist  
2  31/05/1994     BBB        NaN  
3                 BBB    Clerk 1  
4                 BBB    Clerk 2  
5  05/06/1994     ZZZ        NaN  
6                 ZZZ  Executive
```

###### 3. Process for End Date

```
df['End Date'] = df['End Date'].replace('', method='ffill')
df['Start Date Offset Next'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'].squeeze(), format='%d/%m/%Y') - timedelta(days=1)).shift(-1).squeeze().dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

df['Personal No. Next'] = df['Personal No.'].shift(-1)
df['Company Next'] = df['Company'].shift(-1)
df['Title Next'] = df['Title'].shift(-1)

idx_change_end_date = df.apply(lambda row: (row['Personal No.'] == row['Personal No. Next']) & (row['Company'] == row['Company Next']) & (row['Title'] != row['Title Next']) & pd.notna(row['Title']) & pd.notna(row['Title Next']), axis=1)

df.loc[idx_change_end_date, 'End Date'] = df.loc[idx_change_end_date, 'Start Date Offset Next'].squeeze()

df = df.drop(['Company', 'Title', 'Start Date Offset Next', 'Personal No. Next', 'Company Next', 'Title Next'], level=0, axis=1)
```

Result

```
                    Period    Company/Title Personal No.  Start Date  \
0  01/01/1980 - 31/12/1982              AAA            0  01/01/1980   
1               01/01/1980     AAA - Typist            0  01/01/1980   
2  01/07/1990 - 31/05/1994              BBB            0  01/07/1990   
3               01/07/1990    BBB - Clerk 1            0  01/07/1990   
4               01/01/1994    BBB - Clerk 2            0  01/01/1994   
5  01/12/1993 - 05/06/1994              ZZZ            1  01/12/1993   
6               01/12/1993  ZZZ - Executive            1  01/12/1993   

     End Date  
0  31/12/1982  
1  31/12/1982  
2  31/05/1994  
3  31/12/1993  
4  31/05/1994  
5  05/06/1994  
6  05/06/1994
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works! The data was originally from word doc will consider to move this to a database as suggested.